# Как сделать preloader , кода идет запрос Retroft

Tags: java, android

Как сделать Preloader, когда идет запрос при использовании библиотеки Retrofit?

Comment: тут зависит наверное от вашей архитектуры. Покажите каким образом вы посылаете запрос, обрабатываете его и отображаете результат.

Comment: @abbath0767 mvp, в presentere запрос, и вызов метода фрагмента с передачей данных ответа для отображения

Comment: можно сделать отдельный dialogfragment со спиннером загрузки. В момент отправки запроса - отображать его. По завершению работы запроса скрывать его и отображать данные (ну или ошибку). На самом деле способов множество - это первый пришедший на ум. Тут просто на самом деле в вашем вопросе не важно упоминание о ретрофите)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075136/how-can-i-use-retrofit-library-with-progressbar